# How would I use non deprecated API for SKPaymentQueue?

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, skproduct, skpaymenttransaction

I am using using deprecated API and I want to update my code to use non-depcreated code.

So my big question is how do I get the response list?

```
- (void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureId
{
//    SKProduct *myProduct;
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:featureId];
//        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:myProduct];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"purchaseDone" object:nil];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You are not authorized to purchase from AppStore"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (void) purchase: (int) productIndex {
    [self buyFeature: [aryProductIDs objectAtIndex: productIndex]];
}
```

aryProductIDs is defined under (id)init

```
aryProductIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"iap_100OrangeDollars",
                 @"iap_1",
                 @"iap_2",
                 @"iap_1month",
                 @"iap_3month",
                 @"iap_6month",
                 @"iap_12month",
                 @"iap_1lifetime",
                 nil];
```

I am not sure what to use for myProduct (Type SKProduct).

Ive seen many examples using NSSet instead of NSMutableArray. Not sure if I need to change it

Answer (score 1):

First you need to acquire product info on all of your products:

```
NSSet *productsToRequest = [NSSet setWithArray:aryProductIDs];
SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productsToRequest];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

You'll get a delegate callback. You might want to create a dictionary with the response:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products)
    {
        dict[product.productIdentifier] = product;
    }
    self.products = dict;
}
```

You probably want to look at the response and check to see if there `invalidProductIdentifiers` as well, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: it didnt work. productsRequestWithProductIdentifiers is giving me a warning

Comment: Whoops, that's because I had made my own factory method (for unit testing) instead of using alloc / init. Updated above.